# CouchBase Replication Handling

Tags: caching, couchbase

I am new B to CouchBase and looking into replication. One thing I am trying to figure out is how Couchbase handle replication conflicts between two caches. That means:

There are two couchbase servers called S1 and S2 added/replicated together and those servers located in different geographical locations.

Also there two clients (C1 and C2).C1 cache to S1 and C2 cache into S2  objects having a same key but different objects(C1 cache an object called Obj1, C2 cahces Ojb2 object) in same time.

My problem is that what the final value for that key is in the cluster? (what is in S1 and S2 for the key)

Comment: Which replication are you referring to? External replication between clusters (XDCR) or internal replication (TAP) between nodes in a cluster?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Writes in Couchbase

Ignoring replication for a moment and explaining how writes work in a single couchbase cluster.

A key in couchbase is hashed to a [vbucket](http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-manual-2.5/cb-admin/#vbuckets)(shard). That vbucket only ever lives on one node in the cluster so there is only ever one writable copy of the data. When two clients write to the same key, the client that wrote last will "win". The couchbase SDK do expose a number of operations to help with this, such as "[add()](http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-devguide-2.5/#add)" and "[cas()](http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-devguide-2.5/#check-and-set-cas)".

---

## Internal replication

Couchbase does have replica copies of the data. These copies are not writable by the end user and only become active when a node fails. The replication used is a one way sync from the active vbucket to the replica vbucket. This is done memory to memory and is extremely fast. As a result for inter cluster replication you do not have to worry about conflict resolution. Do understand that if there is a failover before data has been replicated that data is lost, again the SDK expose a number of operations to ensure a write has been replicated to Nth number of nodes. See the [observe](http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-devguide-2.5/#monitoring-data-using-observe) commands.

---

## External replication

External replication in couchbase is called XDCR where data is synced between two different clusters. It is best practices not to write the same key in both clusters at the same time. Instead to have a key space per a cluster and use the XDCR for disaster recovery. The couchbase manual explains the [conflict resolution](http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-manual-2.5/cb-admin/#conflict-resolution-in-xdcr) very well but basically the key in the cluster that has been updated the most will win.

If you would like to read more about cluster systems then [CAP Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem) would be the place to start. Couchbase is a CP system.

Comment: Thanks Paddy very much for your detailed explanation and other linked resources.

Comment: Paddy, can you explain what happens when I connect a node to a cluster and this node already contains a key, which also exists in the cluster?
Thank you!